# jigsaw puzzle game. open gl vs  canvas / surfaceView

Tags: android, puzzle

I am trying to build a jigsaw puzzle game in android. Could someone explain what would be the best method of doing this?

1. I was thinking of using a grid of image views and swapping the images when the user slides it.
2. Using open gl?

Which is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go for the first option, since it is:

- easier to implement
- you are using tested and well working facilities
- you do not have to deal with platform dependant issues
- the performance gain for using OpenGL would be a waste, since it is not really needed

Comment: Actually on second thought, wouldn't using  canvas / surfaceView be better?

Answer (score 1):

I agree. You should definitely go for the first option. OpenGL is overkill for your application. But if you are making this app "for fun" you could use OpenGL to get experience and getting familiar with OpenGL until next time you might need it. :)